# Nginx: Rewriting Request using Regex during fcgi_pass

Tags: regex, nginx, mapserver

Any incoming request of the form:

```
http://localhost:19090/wms?map=world&layer=world&mode=map&FORMAT=image/jpg
```

needs to be rewritten to:

```
http://localhost:19090/wms?map=/home/balajeerc/Projects/mapserver/data/wms/world_map/world.map&layer=world&mode=map&FORMAT=image/jpg
```

i.e. the `?map=<mapname>` needs to be transformed into `?map=<full path to mapname.map file>`

Here is the nginx configuration that I have tried so far:

```
    location /wms {
            rewrite (^.*map=)([^\&]*)(\&.*) $1/home/balajeerc/Projects/mapserver/data/wms/world_map/$2.map$3 break;
                            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:19097;
            fastcgi_index  mapserve*;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/balajeerc/Projects/mapserver/bin/mapserve;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 256k; 
            fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
            rewrite_log on;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I get the error:
`msLoadMap(): Regular expression error. MS_DEFAULT_MAPFILE_PATTERN validation failed.` when I try this.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I did some more investigation and I found that the query string is not getting re-written at all. The way I established this was by running the [echo-cpp fastcgi application](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/echo-cpp.cpp). The query string as seen by the final fcgi application is the unmodified original that was sent to nginx.

I suppose that means that this is not a mapserver issue but an nginx issue. It appears that rewrite is doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this after clues from a lot of other nginx related posts. Posting here for posterity.

Apparently, the regex in the 'rewrite' section operates only on paths. That means that everything after the '?' is NOT included in the regex.

What I was trying to do was not just a URL rewrite but modifying one of the request parameters itself. So the way I solved it was as follows:

```
    location /wms {
            if ($args ~* (.*map=)([^\&]*)(\&.*)){
                set $args $1/home/balajeerc/Projects/mapserver/data/wms/world_map/$2.map$3;
            }
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:19097;
            fastcgi_index  mapserve*;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/balajeerc/Projects/mapserver/bin/mapserve;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 256k; 
            fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
            rewrite_log on;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

fastcgi_param  world /home/balajeerc/Projects/mapserver/data/wms/world_map/world.map,

should result in:
http://localhost:19090/wms?map=world